# Scattering Greens function exactly at energy of bound state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, complex-numbers, greens-functions, propagator

I have a small bit of confusion about the expansion I am seeing in literature for the Greens function in time independent scattering theory. For example here is an excerpt from *Scattering Theory of Waves and Particles* by R.G. Newton:

[image]

My question is quite simple. Why in equation 7.26 is there no $\pm i\epsilon$ in the denominator in the first term, i.e. the discrete sum over bound states. I understand that for most energies the $\epsilon$ in this term may be simply ignored, but what if $E$ is exactly equal to some $E_n$, then we have a pole at this energy right? So does this equation have some implicit assumption that we do not take $E$ exactly at the bound state energy? Or is there some other reason?

Comment: You may want to read about *Fano resonance* (scatterning from a bound state): e.g., https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.82.2257

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Green's function $G$ is defined as the solution to
\begin{align}
(E-H)G(E)=1.
\end{align}
You are correct that the Green's function is not well-defined when evaluated at the eigen-energies of the Hamiltonian. However, for a energies corresponding to the continuous part of the Hamiltonian ($E'$ in the textbook notation) we can hope to get around this by defining $G(E')$ via a limiting procedure: we could approach $E'$ from above (i.e., $E+i\epsilon$) or from below (i.e., $E-i \epsilon$), which is defined in Eq. (7.26). (Typically, this process can be understood as taking the analytic continuation of $G$ across the branch cut created by the continuous part of the spectrum.)

Your question relates more to the discrete eigenstates with energy $E_n$. For these, such a limiting procedure does not work and the divergence of the Green's function at these energies is unavoidable. So yes, we cannot "take $E$ exactly at the bound state energy". I suspect that this is why the author has left out the $\pm i \epsilon$. However, there are still benefits of leaving in the $\pm i \epsilon$, which other textbooks use. For example, the density of states can be written as
\begin{align}
N(E)=- \frac{1}{\pi} \Im \, \text{Tr}\, G(E+i\epsilon),
\end{align}
which will yield Dirac deltas at $E=E_n$ (corresponding to the contribution of a discrete state).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Two different situations are possible here, depending on whether one deals with *eigenstates* or a *scattering problem*. The former seems to be the case here - i.e., the spectrum of a Hamiltonian contains both bound and extended states. The examples of this a ubiquitous - a hydrogen atom has bound states for energies $E<0$ and extended for $E>0$. An easily solvable toy example is a negative delta-function potential. Since these are eigenstates of a Hamiltonian, there is no mixing between them (i.e. their eigenfunctions are mutually orthogonal). This would also hold, if a bound state lies within a continuum spectrum, although it is hard to come up with a realistic example.

The situation becomes more interesting in case of scattering - e.g., a particle scattered by an atom or an electron tunneling through or near the quantum dot. In such a scattering problem we start with the states of an isolated atom/quantum dot, but neither is a eigenstate of the joint Hamiltonian. The scattering amplitude in such cases will have resonances associated with the scattering near the bound states. In quantum dots this leads to distinct *resonant tunneling* and *Fano resonance*, depending on whether electron tunnels through the level or passes near it. Once interactions are incorporated it may result in even richer physics - e.g., Kondo effect can be viewed as a resonant tunneling/scattering of an electron pair.